# @ibm-cloud/cloudant: includeDocs: true, still not able to get the entire details of the documents

Tags: websphere, cloudant

service.postAllDocs({
db: 'orders',
includeDocs: true,
limit: 10
}).then(response => { console.log(response.result)});

result only returns:
id, key and value(only contains rev)

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the first 10 docs from the database, including the doc bodies, this code works:

```
const { CloudantV1 } = require('@ibm-cloud/cloudant')
const client = CloudantV1.newInstance()
const DBNAME = 'orders'

const main = async function () {
    const response = await client.postAllDocs({ db: DBNAME, includeDocs: true, limit: 10 })
    console.log(response.result.rows)
}


main()
```

This produces the following output:

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    key: '1',
    value: { rev: '1-0fdc08a2625917344e37eb91661a5568' },
    doc: {
      _id: '1',
      _rev: '1-0fdc08a2625917344e37eb91661a5568',
      fruit: 'banana'
    }
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    key: '2',
    value: { rev: '1-8c4d4385540143ea87f8663193105425' },
    doc: {
      _id: '2',
      _rev: '1-8c4d4385540143ea87f8663193105425',
      fruit: 'apple'
    }
  }
]
```

The document body is under the `doc` attribute in each object.